# Can you let your application fan-out instead of SNS fan-out?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, design-patterns, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I currently have an application that sends messages to the SNS topic. And there are three SQS queues that are subscribed to the topic. I am trying to eliminate the usage of SNS from my architecture because of cost. Is it possible that my application itself acts like SNS and fan-out messages to SQS without the usage of SNS? If there are any drawbacks, what are those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can have your application do that, SNS is just calling the `sqs:SendMessage` API under the hood as well and makes sure it gets a positive response, but there are significant drawbacks:

- You have to maintain the list of queues to send messages to and thereby introduce close coupling
- You have to ensure a message gets sent to **all** queues and handle retries in case of intermittent API failures

Sending messages to one SNS topic is most likely faster **and** less complex than writing and maintaining the code to do that for an arbitrary number of SQS queues.

SNS has a price, but so do developers. Building and maintaining your own solution has a cost - initial and ongoing. If that makes sense from a business perspective, go for it.